# Function to subset and adjust vector

Tags: r, function, vector, quantile

The function is supposed to take a vector and winsorize values at the 1st and 99th percentile (replacing values larger 99th percentile with the 99th percentile, vice versa for values lower than the 1st percentile). I can run the function without any errors, but it does not change the vector that is given as argument. When I run the same code outside the function, it works fine, but I have to do it for many columns in a data.frame, so I would like to be able to pass the function through an apply function.

```
wins <- function(vect, prob = c(0.01, 0.99)){
    #vect is a vector with values to be winsorized
    #prob contains top and bottom percentiles at which to winsorize data in vect

    low_quantile <- quantile(vect, probs = prob[1], na.rm = TRUE)
    high_quantile <- quantile(vect, probs = prob[2], na.rm = TRUE)

    vect[vect < low_quantile] <- low_quantile
    vect[vect > high_quantile] <- high_quantile
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably think that the things happening inside the function magically affect objects outside the function. They do not. You need to explicitly return vect and assign the result of the function to a new object or to an existing object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vect` at the end of your function so that the last element is returned.

```
wins <- function(vect, prob = c(0.01, 0.99)){
#vect is a vector with values to be winsorized
#prob contains top and bottom percentiles at which to winsorize data in vect

low_quantile <- quantile(vect, probs = prob[1], na.rm = TRUE)
high_quantile <- quantile(vect, probs = prob[2], na.rm = TRUE)

vect[vect < low_quantile] <- low_quantile
vect[vect > high_quantile] <- high_quantile
vect
}

wins(1:100)
  [1]  1.99  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  6.00  7.00  8.00  9.00 10.00 11.00 12.00 13.00 14.00 15.00 16.00 17.00 18.00
 [19] 19.00 20.00 21.00 22.00 23.00 24.00 25.00 26.00 27.00 28.00 29.00 30.00 31.00 32.00 33.00 34.00 35.00 36.00
 [37] 37.00 38.00 39.00 40.00 41.00 42.00 43.00 44.00 45.00 46.00 47.00 48.00 49.00 50.00 51.00 52.00 53.00 54.00
 [55] 55.00 56.00 57.00 58.00 59.00 60.00 61.00 62.00 63.00 64.00 65.00 66.00 67.00 68.00 69.00 70.00 71.00 72.00
 [73] 73.00 74.00 75.00 76.00 77.00 78.00 79.00 80.00 81.00 82.00 83.00 84.00 85.00 86.00 87.00 88.00 89.00 90.00
 [91] 91.00 92.00 93.00 94.00 95.00 96.00 97.00 98.00 99.00 99.01
```

**EDIT**
Follow-up question on how to apply this to a data.frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:200,ncol=2))
apply(df1,2,wins) # apply by column
> apply(df1,2,wins)
          X1     X2
  [1,]  1.99 101.99
  [2,]  2.00 102.00
  [3,]  3.00 103.00
  [4,]  4.00 104.00
  [5,]  5.00 105.00
...
```

It also works with a single column as you put in your follow-up:

```
wins(df1$X1)
[1]  1.99  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  6.00  7.00  8.00  9.00 10.00 11.00 12.00 13.00 14.00 15.00 16.00 17.00 18.00
 [19] 19.00 20.00 21.00 22.00 23.00 24.00 25.00 26.00 27.00 28.00 29.00 30.00 31.00 32.00 33.00 34.00 35.00 36.00
 [37] 37.00 38.00 39.00 40.00 41.00 42.00 43.00 44.00 45.00 46.00 47.00 48.00 49.00 50.00 51.00 52.00 53.00 54.00
 [55] 55.00 56.00 57.00 58.00 59.00 60.00 61.00 62.00 63.00 64.00 65.00 66.00 67.00 68.00 69.00 70.00 71.00 72.00
 [73] 73.00 74.00 75.00 76.00 77.00 78.00 79.00 80.00 81.00 82.00 83.00 84.00 85.00 86.00 87.00 88.00 89.00 90.00
 [91] 91.00 92.00 93.00 94.00 95.00 96.00 97.00 98.00 99.00 99.01
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. For some reason this only works when I define a range of values and pass it to it directly as you do in the example. It still does not work when I pass a vector column from a data frame. I have a dataframe with 20 colums so when I pass wins(dataframe$rowname) it does nothing expect print the original row.

Comment: It does work for me using a `data.frame` and `apply`. See my edit.

Comment: There is almost never any need to use `apply(df,2,FUN)` on a data.frame - use `[lsv]apply` instead.